# Lucene NRT: When to commit?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene-nrt

We're refactoring our Lucene host (Lucene.NET 2.9.2), and are implementing Lucene NRT (Near Realtime).

What is the best time/threshold to commit the changes to disk? Is there a golden rule? If it is when the internal ramdisk holds a certain amount of data, how do I get the size?

Once a commit happens we update our database, so I'm not that fearfull of power failures (once the process starts again, it will reindex those documents that have not been committed).

Comment: I have just implemented what sounds like the same scheme in our system.  I decided to do a commit when I have over 1000 uncommitted documents.  I think the number really depends on how many docs/sec you will be adding.  I am also not sure if I can run the commit on a different thread than where I am adding the docs.

Comment: So how fast do you get to 1000 docs? And how big are these docs on average? Our docs are about 200kb.

Comment: Our docs are not that large.  Maybe a couple of kb each.  When the system is running at full capacity, we can get to 1000 docs in about 5 minutes or so.

Comment: If you want to get some points for that, can you add your comment into an answer, so I can also "close" this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just implemented what sounds like the same scheme in our system. I decided to do a commit when I have over 1000 uncommitted documents. I think the number really depends on how many docs/sec you will be adding. I am also not sure if I can run the commit on a different thread than where I am adding the docs.